# Mentioning a particular user

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Currently, we can mention a user using '@' under comments, only if he/she has already commented in that thread. Why our Stack Exchange doesn't allow one to mention any other users in comments so that he/she gets attention of the question or discussion? Particularly, if somebody wants to get attention of a person who has more expertise in that topic?

Comment: This has been debated to death on the main meta. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183237, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131372, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a deliberate choice.

Many of the experts who provide some of the best answers don't want to be able to be paged.

They will visit the site when they can, and answer the questions they feel they should. But they have the complete right to ignore any question they like, for any reason.

When it's been proposed in the past to allow "pinging" a user who hasn't already expressed interest in a particular question, top users have threatened to leave if the feature were implemented.

Answer (score 4):

Just guessing here, but one reason could be that user names are not unique. There are for example 12 "Joe", 10 "Dave", and that's just the first I checked.

Besides, it would seem a little weird because this place was never about individual users. That's one thing I really like about Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time in chat.  You can ping any user, and provide a link to the question.  Users are free to ignore this, so don't abuse it.  If you get no response, don't go begging for a response.

Comment: wait there's a open general CHAT? Can I access it on phone?

Comment: Don't know.  I hate the apps, and find them useless.  You can always use your devices web browser, click the weird though-balloon hamburger in the upper right, and select chat.